# stdout vs console.write in c#

Tags: c#, stdout

I am VERY new to C#/programming and as a learning exercise completed an online challenge to change text to lowercase. The challenge specified it must 'print to stdout' yet I completed the challenge by using `Console.Writeline`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lowercase
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt")) 
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(line.ToLower());
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is `stdout` just another name for outputting to console (submissions could be in many different languages) or did the online code submission just not check the output properly. I have googled 'stdout c#' but don't fully understand the results.

Comment: Stdout means "Standard Output". This typically refers to the console.

Comment: Sounds like a HackerRank challenge, in which you use whatever system printing function the language has to complete it.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies

Comment: @JeroenVannevel to CONSOLE? not really...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In languages like C and C++, there is a global variable with the name `stdout`, which is a pointer to the standard output stream. Thus, `stdout` has become a commonly used abbreviation for "standard output stream" even outside the context of the C language.

Now, what does C# do? Let's have a look at [the documentation of Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Writes the specified string value, followed by the current line terminator, **to the standard output stream**.

So, yes, `Console.WriteLine` does exactly what you need to do. If you need a direct reference to the standard output stream (Hint: you usually don't), you can use the [Console.Out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks for answering my query, it looks like i need to improve my researching skills as well as my coding :-)

Comment: @heinzi Console.Out is a System.IO.TextWriter, not a stream. Console.OpenStandardOutput() is a Stream.