# Not able to send logs using AWSLogDriver

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to use [AWS LOG DRIVER](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/) to send logs to CloudWatch.

Steps -

1. Created a C# console application
2. Added some line as `Console.WriteLine("This is a sample application");`
3. Updated Task.json file to include the Cloud Watch Logs Group and Stream information.
4. Created the docker image and spun it via ECS.

Now in CloudWatch Logs I have started seeing the application logs

**Problem:** I have one ASP.NET MVC 5 Web application, I added same `Console.WriteLine("This is a sample application");` in the MVC Application, but I don't see the logs in Cloud Watch Log Group/Stream.

**Question:** Does that mean that AWSLog Driver will only send logs from **console application**.  But I think that would be a BIG BIG limitiations. Can someone please guide me. Can even ASP.Net application use Console.Out to send logs?

Comment: @Unbeakable were you able to push logs?

Answer (score 1):

First thing,

> The information that is logged and the format of the log depends
>   almost entirely on the container’s endpoint command.

So if the application is parent process of the container it logs to container log or if the process run using some process manager then it will redirect logs to container logs if it configured.

So from the docker perspective,

> docker logs show three I/O streams when they
>   run, called STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR.  STDOUT is usually a command’s normal output, and STDERR is typically used to output error messages. By default, docker
>   logs show the command’s STDOUT and STDERR of docker

[docker-containers-logging](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/)

Now AWS perspective,

> The type of information that is logged by your task's containers
>   depends mostly on their ENTRYPOINT command. By default, the logs that
>   are captured show the command output that you would normally see in an
>   interactive terminal if you ran the container locally, which are the
>   STDOUT and STDERR I/O streams. The awslogs log driver simply passes
>   these logs from Docker to CloudWatch.

[using_cotainer-awslogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

On the basis of above, You Docker container and AWS log-driver nothing to do with log, it only takes logs from application Stdout and Stderr and also depends on the entry point of the docker and AWS log driver consumer container logs.

You need to look into c# stdout and stderr.

[stdout-vs-console-write-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502842/stdout-vs-console-write-in-c-sharp)

[System_Console_Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.out?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_Out)

```
    // Redirect standard output from the console to the output file.
    Console.SetOut(writer);
```

[system.console.setout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=netframework-4.8)

[output-from-net-core-console-app-by-docker-logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029317/output-from-net-core-console-app-by-docker-logs)

[asp-net-core-net-core-console-app-logging-in-docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167186/asp-net-core-net-core-console-app-logging-in-docker-container)