# Return String from C# Command Line EXE to Python Program using TCP

Tags: python, c#

I am using iText7 with C# to read PDFs but the rest of my program is written in Python so I need to return the PDF text from the executable. I know you can't return string from the main function in C# so you are left to write the data somewhere and then retrieve it from your other function. I have managed to write the PDF text to the console and retrieve it from Python using the following code:

C# code

```cs
static void Main (string[] args) 
{
    // ReadPdf gets the pdf text
    string outputText = ReadPdf(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(outputText);
}
```

python code

```py
output = subprocess.check_output([self.PATH_TO_EXE, input_file_name]).decode()
print(output)
```

The problem with this is the bullet points don't seem to be rendering properly (either missing or displays as a ?) because of the text limitations of the console. I have seen people mention using TCP to send the data from C# to Python but I don't know how to use TCP with C#. Suggestions?

Comment: Write it into a file with a defined encoding?

Comment: This looks like an encodeing problem. Are the two programs using the same text encoding? `stdout`, and `stdin` are both raw binary streams. Nothing is modified between the programs.

Comment: After reading your last paragraph again, I suspect you have spotted the reason, but lead us down a garden path related to the inter-process communication between the C# and python. I have added a section to my answer relating to this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an encodeing problem. Are the two programs using the same text encoding? `stdout`, and `stdin` are both raw binary streams. Nothing is modified between the programs.

What you are doing is a simple pipe model.

e.g.
`C#_program | python_program`

However, if they use different encodings then the data will be mangled.

[stdout vs console.write in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502842/stdout-vs-console-write-in-c-sharp) suggests that `Console.WriteLine` just writes to `stdout`, but adds end of line characters. So as long as these end of line characters and the encoding match, then it should work.

It may also be that the problem is not between the C# and the python. The problem may be the console (you hinted at this in your last paragraph). It may be the console does not have the correct fonts.

Some solutions include

- use a different console
- use different fonts
- redirect to a file, and load into a good text editor: `./python_program > output_file; notepad++ output_file` (this is the syntax for any modern OS. You will have to translate for MS-DOS).

Comment: thank you for your help, it wasn't my intention to mislead but as you suspected it was an issue with the font of the pdf that was being read that led to the bullet points being misrepresented.

Comment: Yes. If we knew which path, then we would follow it, and not need help. ☺